# Transformation of Cobb Douglas Utility

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics

So, I need to determine whether or not $u=x^{0.5}y^{0.5}$ exhibits the same preferences as $u'= log(x) + log (y)$. Any tricks I can use here? I've done the logarithmic transformation so that I now have $(0.5)log (x) + (0.5)log (y)$. My guess is, if I multiply these by $2$ I'll get $log (x) + log (y)$ and thereby proving that u and u' refer to the same preferences, but I'm not sure if this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: how does a positive monotone transformation of the utility function affect the consumer's maximization problem?

Edit,

Suppose the optimal bundle for some agent with some utility function $u$ is given by $x^{*} = (x_{1}^{*},x_{2}^{*})$. Suppose then that I take the transformation of $u$ by some strictly monotone function $f$. I claim that $x^{*} = (x_{1}^{*},x_{2}^{*})$ is the optimal bundle for the new utility function $v = f \circ u$.

Suppose not, suppose that there is another bundle $\hat{x} = (\hat{x}_{1},\hat{x}_{2})$ such that $v(\hat{x}) > v(x^{*})$. But by the definition of $v$, we have $$\tag{In}\label{In} f(u(\hat{x})) > f(u(x^{*}))$$ Then, since $f$ is strictly monotone, it is invertible and so from \ref{In} we must have $u(\hat{x}) > u(x^{*})$, which contradicts optimality of $x^{*}$.

The $\ln$ function is one such strictly monotone function on domain $\Re_{+}$.

Comment: I guess the idea behind monotonic transformation is to make it easier to solve but the outcome of the maximization should be the same.

Comment: So I should solve them both and see if I get the same result?

Comment: So could I take both the utility functions i have here, differentiate w.r.t. to x1 for example and then set this equal to zero for both of them and solving each and see if they give the same result?

Comment: Can you show that for any bundle $z = (x,y)$, $u(z) \geq u(z')$ for CB utility, then $v(z) \geq v(z')$ for ln utility? You should not need to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

To see if the preferences between $u$ and $u'$ are the same, simply look at the $MRS$ of both of them to see if they are equivalent.

i.e.

$$MRS_{u}=\frac{MU_x}{MU_y}=\frac{\left(0.5x^{-0.5}y^{0.5}\right)}{\left(0.5x^{0.5}y^{-0.5}\right)}=\frac{y}{x}$$

$$MRS_{u'}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{y}}=\frac{y}{x}$$

$$\Rightarrow MRS_u=MRS_{u'}$$

$\therefore$ $u$ and $u'$ have the same preferences.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Very helpful. I actually just solved it this way before I came on here again to see if there had been any updates. Again thanks!